# How to add Dark mode to Localstorage using Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

Please house, I want to make local storage for my Dark mode.

Here ie my code. Please help add local storage to it:

HTML

```
<div class='KaXTamSwitch'>Dark
<input class='tgl tgl-KaXTam' id='KaXTamNight' type='checkbox'/>
<label class='tgl-btn' for='KaXTamNight'/></div>
```

JS

```
$('#KaXTamNight').click(function(){
    if ($('#KaXTamNight').is(':checked')) {
    $("body").addClass('KaXTamNight');
    }else {
    $("body").removeClass('KaXTamNight');
    }   
    });
```

My CSS is in place.

I only need the functionality of Localstorage added to the javascript.

Comment: Show us what you have tried after researching how to use localStorage. The objective here is for you to do the basic research then post your code attempts to solve your own issue. Others help when your code doesn't work as expected. Stackoverflow is not a new feature coding service

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add to local storage when you check/uncheck the box and while on page load retrieve it and set the class if it was saved earlier

Check in JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/f7jqwmto/

```js
$(() => {
  const theme = 'KaXTamNight';
  const darkMode = localStorage.getItem(theme);
  $('body').toggleClass(theme, darkMode === 'true');

  $('#' + theme).prop('checked', darkMode === 'true').click(function() {
    $("body").toggleClass(theme, $(this).is(':checked'));
    localStorage.setItem(theme, String($(this).is(':checked')));
  });
});
```

```css
.KaXTamNight {
  background-color: #777;
}
```

```html
<div class='KaXTamSwitch'>Dark
  <input class='tgl tgl-KaXTam' id='KaXTamNight' type='checkbox' />
  <label class='tgl-btn' for='KaXTamNight' />
</div>
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/199828/discussion-on-answer-by-joyblanks-how-to-add-dark-mode-to-localstorage-using-jav).